# JavaFX - bind stage.getUserData

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

Can I bind stage.getUserData with TextBox?

My goal is.

If user select my application I save information in method start stage.setUserData in event focusesProperty.

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {       

    try{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Hlavni.fxml"));                                
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:kcl.gif"));
        stage.setTitle("KCL - Evidence hovorů - v1.0");                                                                          
        stage.show();


        /*
            Implementujeme událost - stav kdy uživatel vybere okno aplikace.
        */
            stage.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean lostFocus, Boolean gainFocus) -> {
                if (gainFocus==true) {
                    try {

                        /*
                            Po výběru gainFocus naplníme systémovou metodu stage.setUserData
                            V kontroleru dané vyzvědneme přes zjištěnou stage.getUserData
                            Do metody ukládáme, pouze pokud je null
                        */
                        // Pokud je stage.getUserData == null, uložíme tam číslo, jinak nic.
                        if(stage.getUserData() == null){
                            // Připojíme se do MSSQL a zjistíme telefonní číslo
                            stage.setUserData("607700962");
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        });
```

In controller I need to fill automatically TextBox.

There for I have idea bind stage.getUserData with TextBox.

Comment: Why not just put a method in the controller class and call it?

Comment: How can I call method in controller from method start?

Comment: Same way you call any method... See answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just put a method in the controller class and call it:

e.g.

```
public class MyController {

    // @FXML-annotated nodes from fxml file, e.g.
    @FXML
    private TextField textField ;

    public void initialize() {
        // ...
    }

    // handlers etc...

    public void setInformation(String data) {
        // update text box:
        textField.setText(data);
    }
}
```

and then you can just do

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {       

    try{

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Hlavni.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load(); 
        MyController controller = loader.getController();                               
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:kcl.gif"));
        stage.setTitle("KCL - Evidence hovorů - v1.0");                                                                          
        stage.show();



        stage.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean lostFocus, Boolean gainFocus) -> {
            if (gainFocus) {
                controller.setInformation("607700962");
            }
        });   

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
    // ...
}
```